# For any two functions f and g defined as f (x, y )= (x+1,y+3) and g (x,y)=(x-3,y-2) show that the following statement is true or false.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

> Let $f$ and $g$ be two functions defined on $ \mathbb {R^2} $ as follows $f(x,y)=(x+1,y+3)$ and $g(x,y)=(x-3,y-2)$.
>
> Is the following statement true or false? There  exists $(a,b)$ in $ \mathbb {R^2} $ such that $f(a,b) \neq g(x,y)$ for any $(x,y)$.

The answer is "false". But I think the statement is true. Because for any $(x,y)$ there will be an $(a,b)$ (in fact more than one) such that $f(a,b) \neq g(x,y)$. Am I right?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Set off your latex statements by $

Comment: Thank you. ..please tell me I am right or wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix some arbitrary pair $(a,b)$. Then $f(a,b) = (a+1,b+3)$. Put $(x,y) = (a+4, b+5)$. Then $g(x,y) = (x-3,y-2) = (a+4-3, b+5-2) = (a+1,b+3)$, which is $f(a,b)$.

Thus, no matter what pair $(a,b)$ you choose, there always exists a pair $(x,y)$, such that $g(x,y) = f(a,b)$. This means that the statement is indeed false.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the statement..I thought that if I pick any (x,y)  there will be an  (a,b)  such that f (a,b) $\neq $ g (x,y) which is true.

Comment: Thank you  sir...I want to know one more thing if the statement were like the following " for any (x,y) there exists an (a,b) such that  f (a,b) $\neq $ g (x,y)"   then is it still false?

Comment: @Normal that's not how I interpret it. I believe it's saying "There exists (a,b) such that for all (x,y), we have $f(a,b) \neq g(x,y)$". If we go with your interpretation, then the statement becomes true.